How to insert self-referencing row in a closure table correctly
I was reading about closure tables and I have a problem. This insert will not work if the closure table has no self-referencing row for comment with id 1 so I need to insert it first with insert into [TreePaths] values(1,1,1). But after that if I want to add a ancestor to the comment with id 2 I do not need to insert a self-referencing row for it because it was added in the step when question 2 was used as ancestor. So my question is, do I have to just check if the self-referencing row exists for the descendant, if yes continue, if not create it, or there is a proper way to do this that I missed?
INSERT INTO TreePaths (ancestor, descendant, level)
SELECT t.ancestor, 2, t.level + 1
FROM TreePaths AS t
WHERE t.descendant = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 1;

There is the code to recreate
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Comments] (
    [comment_id] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [comment] [text] NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TreePaths] (
    [ancestor] [int] NOT NULL,
    [descendant] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Level] [int] NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ancestor, descendant),
    FOREIGN KEY (ancestor) REFERENCES [dbo].[Comments](comment_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (descendant) REFERENCES [dbo].[Comments](comment_id)
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Comments] (comment_id, comment)
VALUES (1, 'This is the first comment.'),
       (2, 'This is the second comment.'),
       (3, 'This is the third comment.');


FYI, text was deprecated way back in 2005; you should have long stopped using that data type by now.

As for the prob;em, I tested your code and it worked fine; are we missing something here? db<>fiddle

If you add SELECT * FROM TreePaths; at the end you will see that it created only one row 2,2,1, however the code should have added the comment 2 as ancestor for comment 1. So the correct result would be 1, 2, 2 and 2,2,1

Because you are filtering the data you want to insert; you have a WHERE. At the time of the INSERT there are no rows where descendant has a value of 1; why would you expect such a query to return results if no such rows exist?

Yes I know why it works that way. My question was about the closure table pattern. Do I need to check for the self-referencing row to exist before the insert. This is an example from a book and there are no notes about the checking in there. And since it worked wrong if there are no self-referencing row created before I was wondering if I missed something

If the row is missing, that's a failure of the original insert? If you have partially bad data, you're already smoked, and everything falls apart in my opinion. The inserts into Comments and TreePaths should be in transaction so this isn't an issue. Although, tbh, the TreePath looks like a bad design to me, one usually doesn't keep the self-referencing row and just have the hierarchy of rows ie. Parent=>Child. It's always easy  to materialize Child,Child row if it's needed

Sounds like the book might not be a great resource; I agree with @siggemannen, the need for a self referencing row to start with sounds wrong.

Somewhat off-topic: but last week I dropped $150 on the 3rd edition of Information Modelling and Relational Databases (released last month) - and there's no mention of "closure table" in the book's index (but plenty of other pretentious-sounding terminology!) - I'd like to know more about this pattern but even googling for "closure table" doesn't return that many relevant pages; is it known by another name? The OP said they're using a book, can they share their book's title?

@Dai - Closure table also known as Bridge table.

I found an article on Red Gate (written by Phil Factor no less) by just searching "Closure Table SQL Server", @Dai . Does seem to be resources out there.

The book is called SQL Antipatterns by Bill Karwin and the closure table is one of four ways(adjacency list,path enumeration,nested sets, closure table) described of managing hierarchical data.

Shouldn't you learn more about patterns rather than anti

Well it is a pattern and arguably it is the best ( based on the requirements of course)

Well, the answer to your question is Yes. As per design Self Referencing row for descendant must exist.
In this case , the records for the TreePaths should be as below.

And you can select all records with below query.
SELECT c.*,t.*
FROM [Comments] c
INNER JOIN [TreePaths] t ON c.comment_id = t.descendant
WHERE t.ancestor = 1;


